# How to use Subject in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I've been using Subject from `rxjs` library to make an event emitter in my angular applications but I'm not able to use it in Angular 6 as 
This module isn't present there

```
Cannot find module 'rxjs/Subject'
```

Is being thrown.

Is there a new way for what I've been doing like this.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
private Login = new Subject<boolean>();
```

Then doing this `this.Login.next(true)`

I was able to change state in my project of the user:

```
loginService.Login.subscribe(state => {
      console.log('Login State')
      console.log(state)
})
```

**How to do the above stuff in Angular 6**

Comment: import from rxjs directly like import { Subject } from 'rxjs'

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Angular 6*, you can do it like this:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'; // or import { Subject } from 'rxjs/index';

// ....

private Login = new Subject<boolean>();

// ...

loginService.Login.subscribe(state => {
      // ... your code
})
```

Comment: Alone `import { Subject } from 'rxjs';` is fine